# androidviewclient CalledProcessError

Tags: android, python, androidviewclient

I am trying to run a simple script that contains the following code snippet:

```
from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient
device, serialno = ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit()
vc = ViewClient(device, serialno)
```

The last line above is giving me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Documents\AndroidView\av_settings.py", line 7, in <module>
    vc = ViewClient(device, serialno)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\com\dtmilano\android\viewclient.py", line 2560, in __init__
    subprocess.check_call([self.adb, '-s', self.serialno, 'shell', 'am', 'force-stop', 'com.dtmilano.android.culebratester'])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 186, in check_call
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
CalledProcessError: Command '['C:\\Python27\\\\adb.exe', '-s', 'SH34KW901028', 'shell', 'am', 'force-stop', 'com.dtmilano.android.culebratester']' returned non-zero exit status -1073741515
```

I am unable to figure out what might be causing this error. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure `'C:\\Python27\\\\adb.exe'` is the path to adb?

Comment: Yes, somehow this problem only occurs when running the code in windows. On linux it works fine.

Comment: Perhaps on windows it's assuming the wrong path to `adb`. `ViewClient` constructor can take adb=` parameter, you can try that.